# Use Case Diagram - extend and association to extended UC

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm wondering if I should add association to the extended use case.

In my case actor has to go "through" the base UC in order to get to the extended one. He cannot access it directly.

Should it be:

[image: like this]

or

[image: like that]

All in all, the extended UC is also this actor's use case so it should be marked as an attached one to this actor as well, is extend enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UseCase definition says that, system interacts with external entities (actors) connected to UseCase by association, while executing UseCase. In case of extend relationship, extending usecase (Add New in your example) can be executed independently from extended UseCase (Show list in your example). If your actor interacts with system during execution of Add List UseCase, then association between actor and usecase is necessary. Extending (unlike include) does not have to be applied always, there are usually defined some conditions when to use it.

The conclusion is as follows: Actor should be connected to Add New UseCase if it interact with system during execution of Add New UseCase. You mentioned that actor access UseCase ( it does not matter directly or indirectly), so second diagram is correct.

I recommend you to read specification of UML, section UseCases. You will find exact answer to your question there. [UML Webside](http://www.uml.org)

Comment: It seems that you have already read the UML specification. Can you answer the OP's question more clearly? By showing the "correct" picture?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the Add New can be executed independently.  If not, the actor shouldn't have a direct association with it, which is a way of showing that Add New's only entry point is via show list.